# How to split karma test cases

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have more than 3000 test cases. But karma executes only up to 2000 test case. After it restarts the browser. How to split the test cases into small chunks and integrate the report

Comment: Who told karma can't executes more than 2000 test cases?

Comment: Its executing only up to 2000 test cases.

Comment: Do you see any errors thrown by karma when it stops executing? Else share karma logs by setting `logLevel` value to `config.LOG_DEBUG`

Comment: Its not throwing error, it just restarts the browser